# What's the maximum average path length for a connected graph of given size?

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory

I am looking for an upper bound for the average path langth as a function of N(size of graph).

I know it must be the chain graph(line of vertices that are connected only to their nearest neighbors) and I concluded to the following formula:

[image]

I just can't figure out the pattern.

Comment: And please provide your Python code (I'm assuming it implements the formula?).

Comment: Okay i posted an image of the code. An example would be for N=3 the maximum APL would be the case that the vertices are in line with 2 edges between them, so the APL is indeed 4/3.

Comment: Ok, with the sum not in the denominator anymore, it makes more sense. But isn't it just the average now? How is it a max?

Comment: It is the average path length of the graph that has the N vertices in line connected only to ther first neighbors (N-1 edges, N vertices). And this is the graph that has the maximum average path length between graphs of N vertices

Comment: Ah, makes sense. But what are you asking then? You already have the answer, no? And why is this tagged `python`?

Comment: I am looking for a more straight forward form of the last equation. I am trying to implement the above in Python but yes maybe the tag is a bit misguiding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've understood the question, but I'll try:

- **1 / C. N over 2** equals **((N-2)! * 2)/N!** and can be reduced to **2/(N * (N-1)) = 2/(N^2-N)**
- the sum should evaluate to **(N^3 - N)/3** (rearranging what wolfram alpha says, too much time has passed since my university exams)

So the whole stuff is exactly equal to **(N^2-1)/3(N-1) = (N+1)/3**, which is pretty straightforward to compute and makes me more convinced that I did not understand the assignement.

Comment: How did you calculate the sum again?

Comment: You can compute the sum over i^2 and the sum over i separately and then add them together, taken one by one they are well-known results, should be relatively easy. But I actually used https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=summation+calculator